# James Server connection failure exception

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, james

I'm trying to connect Javamail application to James server, but I'm getting

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:localhost, port:4555;
nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Invalid arguent: connect

Here's the code, which is creating a little problem for me:

```
import java.security.Security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class mail  {

public static void main(String[] argts)
{
Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());


       String mailHost = "your.smtp.server";



        String to = "blue@localhost";



        String from = "red@localhost";
        String subject = "jdk";
        String body = "Down to wind";

        if ((from != null) && (to != null) && (subject != null)  && (body != null)) // we have mail to send
        {

        try {


            //Get system properties
            Properties props = System.getProperties();


            props.put("mail.smtp.user", "red");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", 4555);


            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 4555);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,null);


            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress(to) });
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(body, "text/plain");
            message.setText(body);
            Transport.send(message);


            System.out.println("<b>Thank you.  Your message to " + to + " was successfully sent.</b>");

        } catch (Throwable t) {
           System.out.println("Teri maa ki "+t);
        }


        }

    }




}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", 4555);
```

Those two lines make your code connect to your localhost (your own machine?), port 4555. I presume the SMTP server in question is running on some other host. Put the host name into the first property, and the correct port (usually 25) into the second, and it would work.

If that doesn't help, please provide details on your setup: host where you run SMTP server, port it's listening on, does it use SSL (according to your code it does, eh?), where are you running the client, ...